# Why does base64 encode return bytes instead of string directly?

Tags: python, base64

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(b'bytes required')

>>>b'Ynl0ZXMgcmVxdWlyZWQ='
```

If I understand correctly, base64 is a **bytes <----> string** notation. Then why doesn't it give me string `'Ynl0ZXMgcmVxdWlyZWQ='` directly?

Or does it expect me to do some decoding furthermore?

Like `b'Ynl0ZXMgcmVxdWlyZWQ='.decode('ascii')` or
`b'Ynl0ZXMgcmVxdWlyZWQ='.decode('utf-8')` ? But they result in the same thing.

Comment: codes of `ascii` symbols are same in `utf-8`, that's why result is same.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes and base64 uses only `ascii` characters, why doesn't it gives me string directly? Why would I need the binary result? I wonder :(

Comment: It's "economy" of memory. `b""` string is 1 byte per char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `base64` is meant to be a textual representation of binary data.

However, you are neglecting constraints on the actual implementation side of things.

```
import sys

>>> sys.getsizeof("Hello World")
60
>>> sys.getsizeof("Hello World".encode("utf-8"))
44
```

`str` objects simply take up more system resources than `bytes`. This overhead can lead to non-trivial degradation in performance when working with larger bodies of `base64` encoded data.

I also suspect that since the original python module was ported from python2.7 (which did not distinguish between `str` and `bytes`), that this might also just be a legacy part of the language.

Comment: I thought utf-8 was the default encoding?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that "str objects simply take up more system resources than bytes". Good to know it :)